# Spring Async is blocking and prevents nested async calls

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous, nonblocking

Can anybody tell my is there a way of using the Spring Framework's `@Async` annotation without blocking / waiting on the result? Here is some code to clarify my question:

```
@Service
public class AsyncServiceA {

    @Autowired
    private AsyncServiceB asyncServiceB;

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> a() {
        ThreadUtil.silentSleep(1000);
        return asyncServiceB.b();
    }
}


@Service
public class AsyncServiceB {

    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<String> b() {
        ThreadUtil.silentSleep(1000);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Yeah, I come from another thread.");
    }
}
```

and the configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application implements AsyncConfigurer {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(Application.class);

    private static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            final AsyncServiceA bean = ctx.getBean(AsyncServiceA.class);
            bean.a().whenComplete(LOG::info);
        };
    }

    @Override
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        // omitted
    }
}
```

When I run the application the executor goes through calling `AsyncServiceA.a()` and leaves, but it still holds the thread from the pool waiting on the `CompletableFuture.get()` method. Since there is just a single thread in the pool the `AsyncServiceB.b()` cannot be executed. What I'm expecting is that thread to be returned to the pool after it executes the `AsyncServiceA.a()` and then be available to execute the `AsyncServiceB.b()`.

Is there a way to do that?

Note 1: I've tried with `ListenableFuture` also but the result is the same.

Note 2: I've **successfully** did it manually (without the `@Async`) by giving the executor to each method like so:

AsyncServiceA

```
public CompletableFuture<String> manualA(Executor executor) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        LOG.info("manualA() working...");
        ThreadUtil.silentSleep(1000);
    }, executor)
            .thenCompose(x -> asyncServiceB.manualB(executor));
}
```

AsyncServiceB

```
public CompletableFuture<String> manualB(Executor executor) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        LOG.info("manualB() working...");
        ThreadUtil.silentSleep(1000);
    }, executor)
            .thenCompose(x -> CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(() -> "Yeah, I come from another thread.", executor));
}
```

Here is the `ThreadUtil` if someone was wondering.

```
public class ThreadUtil {

    public static void silentSleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: Added issue for non-blocking Async annotation https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15401

Comment: Well what do you expect with a max pool size of 1... There is only a single thread to process the async methods so basically nothing is async with that. That thread is blocked and not returned to the pool until that has finished.

Comment: I've explained my expectations in the question above - operations on the CompletableFuture are non-blocking until you call get. I don't call get() anywhere so I expect the thread to be done with this CompletableFuture and get returned to the pool. Unfortunately the @Async annotation force call to the get() method and thus the thread is blocked - I want to escape from that. I know this is not asynchronous with thread pool with size 1, but in a non-blocking scenario it would work like a charm.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your last comment. I never reach the b() method call - the a(), which is async returns and blocks the thread **before** b() is called in another thread and there is no thread in the pool for b(). I'm confident b() is never expected because I've added aspect to log when method is entered and when it returns. I've also debugged it tens of times.

Comment: I removed the comment (before I could write another one :) ). Spring is calling `get()` so it works not the same as your example where you are composing stuff. So basically you are comparing apples and oranges and what you want cannot be achieved like this, you would still need to do the composing yourself. Also spring uses for both `supplyAsync` and not `runAsync`. (You might want to check the sources of the `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` to see what spring actually does.

Comment: :) Yes, I saw how the `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` works and I didn't like it (because I want to be in control when to call `get()`). I hoped that there is some workaround on this (with config or something), because it doesn't make sense to me why would it work like that (blocking execution). Well, maybe I'm asking for too much and should do the custom solution, then wait for the official release of Java 9 and Spring 5.0 with its reactive features.

Comment: The Spring Async existed before the `CompletableFuture` and is intended for async handling not for non-blocking support that is a different story. So you would have to use the reactive part for that (or ask for enhancement of the async support to do the composing you want).

Comment: Ah, alright. This makes a bit more sense now. Could you extract an answer from your comment? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@Async` support has been part of Spring since Spring 3.0 which was way before the existence of Java8 (or 7 for that matter). Although support has been added for `CompletableFuture`s in later versions it still is to be used for simple async execution of a method call. (The [initial implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3.0.x/org.springframework.aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java) reflects/shows the call).

For composing callbacks and operate non blocking the async support was never designed or intended to.

For non blocking support you would want to wait for Spring 5 with its reactive/non-blocking core, next to that you can always [submit a ticket](https://jira.spring.io) for non-blocking support in the async support.

Comment: Thanks! FYI I added the issue - link in the updated description.

Answer (score 3):

I've responded on the ticket https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15401 but I'll respond here as well to qualify the response by M. Deinum.

@Async by virtue of how it works (decorating the method call via AOP) can only do one thing, which is to turn the entire method from sync to async. That means the method has to be sync, not a mix of sync and async.

So ServiceA which does some sleeping and then delegates to the async ServiceB would have to wrap the sleeping part in some @Async ServiceC and then compose on ServiceB and C. That way ServiceA becomes async and does not need to have the @Async annotation itself..

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but wouldn't this approach still tie up the thread from which ServiceA is called with an underlying get() call on each of the @Async service calls? If so wouldn't this be frowned upon when ServiceA is initiated from a web service?